# In Russian, you can express a dialog without starting a new paragraph each time. Can you do something similar in English?

Tags: punctuation

So, in my native language (Russian), you can write something like this (dashes separate lines of two interlocutors),

> "Hey, John!" — "Hey, Pete!" — "How's the family?" — "So far so good!"

I want to do the same in English. Can I? If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: So you mean those dialogues form part of a paragraph that has other text materials in it? What are the dashes in between them - text?

Comment: The dashes simply separate one line from the other

Comment: This isn't about learning English; it's style / writing advice. The problem with what you suggest, of course, is that if you introduce a bit of description in between the replies, and then continue the same person's speech without mentioning their name again (because that's what you now have to do, or at least indicate in text the same person is continuing to speak), no one will know anymore who's talking. The most annoying books I've read have been those where I had to deduce from some hint in the ensuing description whose line that was or, worse, when I had to count lines and start over.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I agree with userr2684291. If you decide to incorporate a style that is not widely used, then you should expect readers to get confused (and in some cases even frustrated). There is nothing wrong with following a different style. But you have to think about your audience and what they expect. Em dashes have specific purposes - I don't think you can use em dashes like that.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev And I don't think you can actually pinpoint who downvoted the question. Just so you know I did not downvote this question either. But here are few reasons why someone might have. Your question does not conform to the guideline in the help center: [How do I ask a good question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You don't mention what research you have done to solve your problem - that is quite important here in ELL. Your question is also hard to understand - you don't provide examples (show us a written paragraph with normal text and dialogues).

Comment: You asked "Can I? What are the alternatives?". Without further context and examples, this is *primarily opinion based* (as we don't exactly see a body of text with your style, everyone may not have the same base scenario) and *too broad.* Both are off-topic. These are just a few reasons why someone might have downvoted the question.

Comment: You can write that way if you want. To a native speaker such as myself the way you wrote looks very cluttered to the point of me not even wanting to read the text so as to try to figure out who's saying what. Also, you could probably improve this question by not saying "so" at the beginning.

Comment: Why do you want to limit it to a single paragraph?

Comment: Because I don't want it to stand out visually

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Stand out from what? I would note that to a native English speaker, non-standard punctuation is going to stand out far more than typical dialogue, even with line/paragraph breaks. The only place I've seen something similar to your example is rare cases in fiction, and never as meaningful dialogue. I've seen it used to indicate that there's a ton of noise in a crowd, and the narrator is overhearing bits and pieces of other conversations, but nothing with any linear or logical sense. I doubt that's the sense you want to convey.

Comment: @Katy From the rest of the paragraph, of course! I want breaks to separate one paragraph from the other; at the same time, I don't want a paragraph to be visually chopped to pieces (due to blank spaces) because of incorporated dialogs

Comment: I don't like the prospect of that Jeff getting 50 points in 6 days for nothing, not at all

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev What kind of writing is this, and who is the audience? Fundamentally, I think you're stuck on something that just isn't an issue if you have native English speakers and readers as your audience. English style guides are very consistent that different speakers get different paragraphs. Following standard paragraph and dialogue style isn't going to "stand out" visually even though there is spacing around them--the rules that we are used to function almost invisibly in our daily lives, just like a native speaker's familiarity with idiom or irregular language constructions.

Comment: If you are interested, give this a read [Must every piece of speech get its own paragraph?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/6977/must-every-piece-of-speech-get-its-own-paragraph) from Writing SE. It's very relevant. A suggestion would be to thoroughly read every answer and not skim over.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Depending on what kind of writing you're doing, an option may be to summarize the dialogue instead of transcribing it. "John and Pete exchanged greetings and inquired after each other's families."

Comment: @Katy No. 5 more to go...

Comment: @AIQ I saw no suggestions as to my objective

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev No approval of your style (both here and in that post) is a suggestion/answer in and of itself. That style of putting dialogues (from 2 or more people) from a direct discourse in one paragraph is unusual.

Comment: @AIQ Who said I want my writing to be usual? I just want to confuse a reader as little as possible (doing dialogs within a single paragraph, I mean). For example, there's an issue with interrupting which is expressed, too, with a dash. Too many dases (both to separate lines and express interrupting) may be not the best idea. Please suggest something better and cut that neverending "no, no, no, you can't" drone. Remember the Alamo! (whatever the heck that means; I just read this is something which is supposed to be encouraging)

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev If you insist on putting dialogue within a single paragraph, it will be confusing to English readers. Frankly, you haven't given any compelling reason for why you want to structure your writing in an alternative way. You also haven't answered any questions about the kind of writing you're doing that might help us make suggestions about what would be least disruptive. Is this fiction, academic, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It quite simply is not standard English orthography to put multiple utterances by different speakers in the same paragraph.

I know it's not what you want to hear, but we have all had the rule drilled into us since middle school:   New speaker -- new paragraph.  Every time.

The exception is reportative first person, where a narrator is telling others what a person said or did; in that case the speech counts as the person speaking "now", not the person speaking "originally".

This makes a lot of written English have many, many paragraphs when there is dialogue.  That's just the way it is.  The only alternatives are to "break the rules", and most English readers will find this very jarring or confusing.  Certainly if you just used the Russian emdash most English readers would not know that the speaker had changed - and even when they understood what you were doing, it would still be slow and difficult to read and seem rushed or jumbled.

There are some authors that do this with frequency, precisely to generate that jarring effect or confusion. But they would fail a writing class.

Comment: I do wonder if it would be natural by now, especially to younger readers, to see dialogue between two people on alternating sides of the page, as the dialogue might appear in an "instant message" session!  But this is obviously still "rule breaking", and although it's not technically paragraphs, it's still a break with lots of space in between.

Answer (score 7):

I keep saying this: capitalization, punctuation, and paragraphing are specified in style guides. Style guides differ. Nor do capitalization, punctuation, and paragraphing even exist in speech, which is probably 95% of the English uttered. I'd say that they are not part of grammar strictly defined. No one says e. e. cummings wrote bad English because he was idiosyncratic in his capitalization.

But most style guides have many commonalities one of which is putting the speech of different characters in separate paragraphs. If you do not follow that guidance, you are very likely to confuse and annoy native English readers. Writers like e. e. cummings are the exception.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev You are of course free (in many countries anyway) to say or write whatever you like, however you like. Native speakers of the language you do it in are similarly free to find the way you said or wrote it confusing, strange, and counter to the norms of the language. On this site we try to advise people so that they can avoid the latter. Jeff has done that here, so I'm upvoting the answer.

Comment: There are no situations when you can't start a new paragraph. (except in stack exchange comment boxes).  If you are so limited in formatting that you can't start a new paragraph, then the context is informal enough that there are no fixed style rules. Do whatever you think is best. Your solution is not standard, but it is fine (if you really need to quote a dialogue in a comment box)

Comment: "Paragraphing police" - after an arrest, expect a long sentence.

Comment: So this question isn't about speech, but orthography.  That's fine.   I'm sure the author of the question is aware that his question is not about speech.  I don't feel like you've answered him at all.

Comment: @BadZen My point, which you seem to have missed entirely, is that the OP CAN do what he wants without violating any rules of English grammar and without being undecipherable. That is EXACTLY what he wanted to be told. I even gave him an example of an author who consistently ignored common orthography yet was admired. I warned him, however, that what he wants to do would likely annoy or confuse many readers. What did you want me to do? Lie by telling the OP that his desired orthography would be indecipherable. Or lie by indicating that it would found acceptable by many readers.

Comment: He asked a question about orthography:  are there suitable (orthographic) alternatives to new-speaker-new-paragraph?   Your answer is completely summarized by: "some style guides give orthographic rules for English, most recommend the rule you are trying to avoid."  That literally does not address the question.  The answer is that there are not, in fact, any good alternatives that readers will recognize and navigate.